# What do you call the constituents of a robotic arm?

Tags: word-request

You know in a upper human limb, there's the forearm and arm, but in robotic arms what do you call the forearm and the arm of the robotic arm. What would both of them be described as? I am thinking bars, but that word doesn't seem to really describe what they are.

Here's an example sentence:

> The robotic arms had several ___ attached together by huge robotic joints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe roboticists have a specific term for this, but I don't know one. I'd use one of the generic words: "segments" or "sections".

Answer (score 0):

Roboticists do have a specific term: **links**.

> The robotic arms had several links attached together by huge robotic joints.

The sort of robotic arm you're describing is called a [serial manipulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_manipulator), though this is a technical term unlikely to be understood by the average reader. The robotic counterpart of the human hand is called an [end effector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_end_effector), another somewhat technical term, and robotic end effectors can generally do more than grabbing things (e.g. welding).

"Segments" or "sections" both would work fine, but I think most English speakers would understand "links" too. The nice thing about "links" is that it emphasizes that they're mostly just there to connect the joints (and the end effector) together.